# Pusher receives no events

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

i am using laravel with pusher to send an event message to pusher. the code is in my controller which is a post controller, triggered when an input form is submitted. below is my code. what am i doing wrong? there is no event received.
this is an ajax call route based controller.

```
$pusher = new Pusher( env('PUSHER_KEY'), env('PUSHER_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'), array( 'encrypted' => true ) );
$pusher->trigger( 'test_channel', 'my_event', 'hello world' );
```

Comment: Do you see the events in the debug console on https://dashboard.pusher.com/?

Comment: no i don't see any event

Comment: I haven't used this in Laravel yet but from my reading shouldn't you be using the `broadcast()` method? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#broadcasting-events

Comment: I do agree with `@Eric Tucker` that using the built in Laravel functioning for Pusher and Broadcasting could be very useful to you unless you have a strong reason to stick with the /vinkla/laravel-pusher package.

Comment: @MohamedAthif in that case the events must not be reaching Pusher. I would recommend using tcpdump/Wireshark to check if the events are being sent over the network at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also assuming you have set up your Pusher account correctly and that your environment variables are correct.

If so, you may need to ensure you are using the correct Cluster (the default is fine for the US, but outside the East coast of the US for example, the cluster must be explicitly defined).

Update:

Controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Vinkla\Pusher\Facades\Pusher;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class TestPusherController extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;


    public function test(){
        $arr = array('test' => 'hello world 2') ;
        $pusher = new Pusher( env('PUSHER_KEY'), env('PUSHER_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'), array( 'encrypted' => true, 'cluster' => 'ap1' ) );
        $pusher::trigger( 'test_channel', 'my_event', $arr);

        return $arr;
    }

    public function shortenedTest(){
        $message = 'Hello world';
        Pusher::trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', ['message' => $message]);
    }

}
```

In web routes:

```
Route::get('testPusherController', 'TestPusherController@test');
Route::get('shortenedTestPusherController', 'TestPusherController@shortenedTest');
```

I have got this working on a fresh install of vinkla/pusher following the setup steps in https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-pusher, on Laravel 5.3, using the built in PHP server and Connecting to the EU server (I do not have any Pusher apps using ap1 at this time).

You will notice a small number of changes to the coding in the controller to get the correct format. You must 'use' the Pusher facade above the controller.

For completeness, I have added a neater way of working with this where you can set the Pusher credentials in the Config/pusher.php file without the need to setup the connection for each use. This can be seen in the shortenedTest() method on the controller.

```
<?php

return [

    'connections' => [
        'main' => [
            'auth_key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_CLUSTER')
            ],
            'host' => null,
            'port' => null,
            'timeout' => null,
        ],

        'alternative' => [
            'auth_key' => 'your-auth-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'app_id' => 'your-app-id',
            'options' => [],
            'host' => null,
            'port' => null,
            'timeout' => null,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: cluster is AP1, im using Vinkler/pusher package. there is absolutely no response. but i can trigger a connection with a front end javascript. just not controller

Comment: Being able to connect with Javascript means your Pusher App should be set up correctly for the code listening for messages. Your Server side code is not related to this and must be set up correctly to broadcast the messages.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help ;-)